# Does db_query support UNION?

Tags: database

I have a query that contains a UNION operator. If I ran my query it runs perfectly straight on the database but I am getting an empty result in Drupal.

Here is a simplified version of the query:

```
$result = db_query("
    SELECT *
    FROM (
    SELECT
    agent_number
    FROM table1
    WHERE agent_number IN (':agent_numbers')
    UNION
    SELECT
    agent_number
    FROM table2
    WHERE agent_number IN (':agent_numbers')) t", array(
      ':agent_numbers' => $agent_ids,
    )
  )->fetchAll();
```

Is it that `db_query()` doesn't support UNION?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, db_query() does support UNION. I had a problem with my query:

```
WHERE agent_number IN (':agent_numbers')
```

Should be:

```
WHERE agent_number IN (:agent_numbers)
```